# Java Line drawn disappeared in some points

Tags: java, image, line, draw, japplet

I'm developing an applet in which the user can put some markers and draw lines over an image using the mouse.

The space where I put lines and markers is a JPanel. I created the markers as JComponents and the lines are simple Line2D.

Markers are transparent squares with a circle filled up with color.

I put on some mouselisteners on the JPanel for zooming and dragging of the image. There are mouselisteners also on markers, and for the paths I add new mouselisteners to the JPanel. When I have to draw a line, I remove the marker's listeners.

I have no problem in creating the markes. The lines can start only from a marker or another line. When I try to draw a line, I click on a marker and drag the mouse. I can see the line on the transparent parts of the marker, and, if I pass near another one, I can see the line show up also in these... but nothing in the space between the two markers.

I don't know which is the problem, I override the **paintComponent** method of the JPanel, and I use its Graphics2D.

If you need something ask freely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out the solution thanks to a casual test.

In the **paintComponent** of the JPanel, after drawing the lines, I was missing these two commands:

```
this.revalidate();
this.repaint();
```

Now all works well.

Comment: +1 for answering your own question (& telling others the solution).